# Is there a way to make user select a color/colour with only the option that you give them in JavaScript/HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

Hey I was wondering if there is a way that you can make the user choose a colour/color with the options that you give them? I know there is a way to let user select a color/colour of thier choices but is there a way that you give the user only three options that change the background colour/color? for instance let say I want the user to only have the choice between black and blue how would I code this?

This is what I tried:

HTML Page:

```
<div class="colour selector">
    Pick a color <input onchange="colorSelected(this)" type="color">
  </div>
```

JavaScript Page:

```
function colorSelected (element) {
    document.body.style.background = element.value
}
```

But i want to be able to give the user limted options like only three colours (red, blue & yellow)

Comment: Put the options you want them to have in a `<select>`

Comment: @mykaf I'm kind of new to coding how would I go about it would it look like this <select> background-colour: red, blue, green</select>

Comment: Mozilla Developer Network is a great resource: [select element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let select = document.getElementById("select");
let text = document.getElementById("text");

select.onclick = function() {
  switch (select.value){
      case "red":
        text.style.color = "red";
        select.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      break;
      case "pink":
        text.style.color = "pink";
      select.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
      break;
      case "blue":
        text.style.color = "blue";
      select.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
.color1{
  background-color:red;
}
.color2{
  background-color:pink;
}
.color3{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option hidden selected value="">Choose a color</option>
  <option value="red" class="color color1"></option>
  <option value="pink" class="color color2"></option>
  <option value="blue" class="color color3"></option>
</select>
<p id="text">Some text</p>
```

Edited version

Comment: That is basically what I am looking for except it being a text I want the user to be able to see a visual colour/colour. I appreciate the response/answer thank you.

Comment: @DanyalChatha Check out the edited version

Answer (score 0):

Use a select with option for each choice.

Use your function in an eventListener that will pass the event object as an argument so you can get the value from the select (which is the `event.target`):

```js
const mySelect = document.getElementById("my-select");
mySelect.addEventListener("change", colorSelected);

function colorSelected(event) {
  document.body.style.background = event.target.value
}
```

```html
<select id="my-select">
  <option value="pick" hidden>Pick a color</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
```